# Как определить ошибку в виджете CListView в yii1?

Tags: php, yii, виджет

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                'itemView'=>'_detail',
));
```

в файле _detail

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data' => $data,
'attributes' => array(
    'id',
    'district_id',
),
));
```

Ошибка в браузере require(): Filename cannot be empty

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего скрипт не может найти сам файл _detail.php. Необходимо убедиться, что файл лежит в одной папке с файлом, в котором вызывается виджет, а если используется тема, в папке темы с соответствующим путем. Для надежности заново написать имя файла, скопировать и вставить в виджет.